# How can I get python's Maildir to read the updated state?

Tags: python, email, maildir

I've written some code in python that opens the Maildir, updates "new" messages to be in "cur", flushes and closes the mail dir. The problem is that when I read the very same Maildir again after this using the script, it's still reading all emails as new!

(if I actually have a look in the OS directly, I can the see that the mail files have been moved from Maildir/new to Maildir/cur)

Any ideas?

```
mail = Maildir(self._mail_dir, factory=MaildirMessage)
mail.lock()
for i, (key, m) in enumerate(mail.iteritems()):
  if m.get_subdir() == "new":
    m.set_subdir("cur")
    m.add_flag("S")  # Message seen
    mail[key] = m
  do_something_else(m) 
mail.flush() 
mail.close()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the fix. Basically I only need to pass **factory=None** instead of **factory=MaildirMessage**.

Reading the documentation in the link below it seems like **factory=None** actually picks MaildirMessage factory but apparently it also adds extra behavior.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html#maildir